# Invoke code from string. parameter not accepted

Tags: c#, invoke

I wish to invoke code that is in selected txt file. It works fine until file content is something simple like "Text string". It also works if i pass string parameter into it. But when i try passing an object like in my case Global it fails. Error is: "The type or namespace name 'Global' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Here is some code..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scripting scriptObj = new Scripting();
        scriptObj.fileName = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
        scriptObj.tekst = File.ReadAllText(this.openFileDialog1.FileName);
        string exit = scriptObj.GetAction();
        this.label1.Text = exit;
    }


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public class Global
{
    public string fileName = "test string";
}

public class Scripting
{

    public string tekst = "";
    public string fileName = "";

    public string MyMethod1(Global obj) { return (obj.fileName); }

    public string GetAction()
    {
        string sourceCode = @" namespace WindowsFormsApplication2 { public class Scripting { public string MyMethod (Global obj) { return (" + tekst + "); }}}";
        var compParms = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };

        var csProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults compilerResults = csProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compParms, sourceCode);
        if (compilerResults.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
            foreach (CompilerError error in compilerResults.Errors)
            {
                errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                       error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
            }
            return errors.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Global newGlobal = new Global();
            newGlobal.fileName = "TEsTfileNameToOutput";
            object typeInstance = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApplication2.Scripting");
            MethodInfo mi = typeInstance.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
            string methodOutput = (string)mi.Invoke(typeInstance, new object[]{ newGlobal });
            return methodOutput;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Why does

```
public string MyMethod (Global obj) { return (" + tekst + "); }
```

not take Global as param, but it works ok with MyMethod1

```
public string MyMethod1(Global obj) { return (obj.fileName); }
```

Content of selected file is: obj.fileName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included a reference to the current assembly, which is the assembly *declaring* `Global`. Therefore the compiler has no idea which type you're talking about.

You need to set the [`ReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in the `CompilerParameters` that you're creating.

Comment: what should i add? i tried: compParms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Global"); and its: "Metadata file 'Global' could not be found"

Comment: @NinjaOnTilt: Well what's your assembly called? The one containing all this code, that is. I doubt that it's called `Global.exe` or `Global.dll`. Perhaps `WindowsFormsApplication2`, given the namespace name? (I'd hope you'd come up with a better name, mind you...)

Comment: lol. sorry but i have no idea yet what my assembly is called. i put all program code up there. It's just `public class Global
{
    public string fileName = "test string";
}` to me. Is : "WindowsFormsApplication2.exe" it?